# csv module python3.1

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Im using the following in Python2.x ;

```
import csv
f = open('test.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow((fpath, md5sum, size)) # <str>, <str>, <int>
```

This works without any problems. However, when I run this in Python3, I get a TypeError.

```
writer.writerow((fpath, md5sum, size))
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be bytes or buffer, not str
```

Of course, writing out the data to a file in opened in non-binary mode would do the trick, but I like the way Unicode is handled in Py3 and wish to specifically encode data before writing to a file and decode it when reading from it.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: So, where exactly you're decoding/encoding data and how is it related to the binary mode?

Comment: Surely the point of the unicode/bytes split is that you *don't* have to deal with encoding/decoding yourself? If you want to use a different codec from the default, see Ignacio's answer.

Comment: Could you elucidate on your point of "not having to deal with the encoding yourself"? What does the unicode/bytes split have to do with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f = open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
```

Comment: This answer is OK for non-Windows systems. For portability all 3.X csv files should be opened with `newline=''` whether reading or writing. Writing case is not yet documented; bug report raised ... http://bugs.python.org/issue7198